# Javascript Regex for any one mandatory special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regex for password validation

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&#^~|_.`+=-])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&#^~|_.`+=-]{12,25}/
```

- Allows minimum 12 and maximum 25 characters.
- Must have at least one number.
- One upper case
- One lowercase
- One special character.(Any one)

It is working fine.

But I need to mention mandatory fields for special characters `` [$@$!%*?&#^~|_.`+=-] ``, is there any way I can create a regex which can be treated any special character. For example **Pras022222()1** this wont treat as valid password since I didn't mention **()** this in the list.

Comment: Please don't arbitrarily place an upper limit on the length of a password

Comment: Why don't you just do separate checks for upper case, lower case, digits , special characters and length?

Comment: You can use [`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{12,25}$`](https://regex101.com/r/6qtpCg/1) where `\W` matches any character that is not a word character i.e. `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @anubhava but that would allow `()` when they're not valid according to requirements

Comment: @phuzi: It is valid, any special character is valid

Comment: @phuzi OP is asking how to accept any special character without specifying each of special character.

Comment: @anubhava your regex is not accepting underscore

Comment: Can you post it as an answer, I can accept that

Comment: Alternative to a regex, have a look at [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and perhaps just accept characters above a certain range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with `\W`:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_\W]).{12,25}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6qtpCg/2)

Here character class `[_\W]` will enforce presence of any non-word character or a underscore.

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Assert start
- `(?=.*[a-z])`: Assert that we have a lowercase letter ahead
- `(?=.*[A-Z])`: Assert that we have a uppercase letter ahead
- `(?=.*\d)`: Assert that we have a digit ahead
- `(?=.*[_\W])`: Assert that we have a underscore or a non-word character ahead
- `.{12,25}`: Match a string with 12 to 25 characters
- `$`: Assert end